# How is this C chord constructed on guitar?

Tags: guitar, chords, fingering

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoW9B8NOPvU) on Black Magic Woman from Justin Guitar and at 6:18 he plays the C Chord in the following way. Since the C Chord consists of notes C, E, and G I notice that his index finger is on C and his ring finger is on G, from there I know that the E can be open. My misunderstanding comes from the open B string; how is he muting this string? I have tried muting this string with my middle finger and my ring finger with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no open B string.  He is fretting it with the third finger, so it sounds an "E".  Like this:

[image: C major chord]

[Image Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHVGoc9IaiM)